# Encrypt Decrypt string in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

I am trying to encrypt decrypt string in asp.net. Encryption is working perfectly but I have an issue in decryption. When I am trying to decrypt the string I am getting empty string. 
Here is the code:

```
private const string Key = "AOF1J2GN-O4K6-P6MW-L0R2-LE6N2V9G1P5A";
public static string Encrypt(string data, string key = null) {
    if (key == null)
        key = Key;
    RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = GetRijndaelManaged(key);
    ICryptoTransform transform = rijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor();
    byte[] plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(transform.TransformFinalBlock(plainText, 0, plainText.Length));
    return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(base64String);
}
public static string Decrypt(string data, string key = null) {
    if (key == null)
        key = Key;
    RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = GetRijndaelManaged(key);
    byte[] encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
    byte[] plainText = rijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainText);
}
private static RijndaelManaged GetRijndaelManaged(String key) {
    RijndaelManaged objRijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged();
    objRijndaelManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC; //remember this parameter
    objRijndaelManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7; //remember this parameter
    objRijndaelManaged.KeySize = 128;
    objRijndaelManaged.BlockSize = 128;
    byte[] pwdBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[0x10];
    int len = pwdBytes.Length;
    if (len > keyBytes.Length) {
        len = keyBytes.Length;
    }
    Array.Copy(pwdBytes, keyBytes, len);
    objRijndaelManaged.Key = keyBytes;
    objRijndaelManaged.IV = keyBytes;
    return objRijndaelManaged;
}
```

I have tried some other sample codes too but got same result. There may be some issue in the "Key" but I am not sure.
Any help?

Comment: Please provide the code that uses the code you've already shown.

Comment: It works fine for me, I used your code exactly except for the UrlEncode part. See this LinqPad script: http://share.linqpad.net/xlgptx.linq . Though I would not suggest using the same key and iv.

Comment: As Artjom hints at, you must be passing the string into Decrypt differently than it comes out of Encrypt. Like maybe you URL Decode it, or Base 64 decode it.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I accidentally passed an empty string for encryption that's why I was getting an empty string on decrypting. Thanks for your help

Comment: Don't use Encoding.GetBytes() to make your key. Look up the PasswordDeriveBytes class.